# How do I use an element in for loops to create a variable of the element?

Tags: python-3.x

First post here, hopefully soon I'll be able to look back and see this is as a rookie question!

I'm trying to make a loop that creates an empty dictionary for each brand, to be used by a seperate loop later that adds key value pairs into it like the year and model.

```
carmakerlist= ('Ford', 'Honda','Lamborghini') #actual list is longer
for i in carmakerlist:
    i = i.lower()
    i = {}
print(ford)
```

When I print 'ford', it says there isn't a variable stored named 'ford'.

How can I get the 'i' in the for loop to save the dictionary as the element it's iterating over's name? Is this even possible or am I tackling the problem the wrong way?

Comment: Welcome to SO! First, note that `i` gets assigned the next item in `carmakerlist` on every iteration of the loop, so you shouldn't be assigning to that. Why not have one dictionary with keys as each of the car types? Instead of making a dictionary for each of them.

Comment: ALWAYS maintain a container for all the variables with the same type. It will be better just to have `my_dict = {i:{} for i in carmakerlist}`. But if you insist on creating them on the global enviroment then you will have to do `for i in carmakerlist: globals()[i] = {}`. In the first instance you will have all to call `my_dict['ford']` for example, while in the second instance, you will just call `ford`

Answer (score 0):

New or "*seperate*" variables aren't usually dynamically created in the way you're thinking (though it may be possible in python using `globals()` like in @onyambu's comment) - each variable is usually explicitly named by you in the code file while initialising it.

What happens in your example is that there's just one variable `i` used by the for loop, which keeps storing the next value in `carmakerlist` each time an iteration begins. Then, you reassign it to a new empty dict (the same var `i` itself stores that created dict, no new variable is made for it); then at the next iteration this repeats again and so on.

For creating and storing several values, you should create a 'container' variable that is a [collection/sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Another Python concept - that collection should be *mutable* (meaning its contents can be modified by the program later on, without entirely re-assigning it). A `list` is one such type. Note that `carmakerlist` in your code is a sequence of other strings, *but* it's a `tuple` which is immutable.

Using a `list` would work something like this -

```py
car_data = []  
for i in carmakerlist:
    car_data.append({})
```

But unfortunately this doesn't name the individual dicts - you can only access them through index numbers `0`, `1`, etc, so it's a better idea to use a container `dict` (as people have already suggested in the comments), which is also a mutable sequence type.

Finally, this is what you might want to do -

```py
car_data = {}
carmakerlist = ('Ford', 'Honda','Lamborghini') #actual list is longer
for i in carmakerlist:
    car_data[i.lower()] = {}
print(car_data)         # Print the dict of all the other dicts
print(car_data['ford']) # Just the ford dict
```

Comment: Thanks!!! There were a few tuples littered throughout the rest of my code so explaining that they are immutable helped A LOT with the other errors i was getting as well.